# Bluetooth device connected/paired but it is not recognized by sound system after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, 22.04, pipewire

After upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04, I'm facing a problem with my Bluetooth headset -- and all Bluetooth devices related to sound, which are the only ones I use. All of them connected/paired as usual but are not recognized by the sound system. In sum: not working.

Intuitively, I think the problem is related to Pipewire. What should I do? Besides the information I provide bellow, let me know what else I should share so you can guide me here. Thanks!

> sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth

```
[    5.880568] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.880590] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.880591] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.880593] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.880595] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.880597] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.953632] Bluetooth: hci0: Legacy ROM 2.5 revision 1.0 build 3 week 17 2014
[    5.953637] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 32
[    6.030451] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.030454] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.030457] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.136540] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.136546] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.136550] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

> sudo service bluetooth status -l

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-04-26 16:03:37 -03; 18min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1237 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18853)
     Memory: 2.6M
        CPU: 780ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1237 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 26 16:03:49 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Apr 26 16:03:49 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Apr 26 16:03:49 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Apr 26 16:03:49 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.87 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Apr 26 16:04:45 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Apr 26 16:05:28 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.45 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/3
Apr 26 16:09:12 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 04:52:C7:3C:3F:05: Host is down (112)
Apr 26 16:09:14 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:connect_cb() HUP or ERR on socket: Connection reset by peer (104)
Apr 26 16:09:26 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 04:52:C7:3C:3F:05: Host is down (112)
Apr 26 16:09:28 legion-y530 bluetoothd[1237]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:connect_cb() HUP or ERR on socket: Connection reset by peer (104)


``
```

Comment: Have you tried removing and pairing again?

Comment: Yes, @ChanganAuto . Countless times.